# Converting number of years to date using dart

Tags: date, dart

I've been trying to convert number of years to date using dart. The format has to be `YYYY-MM-DD`. There is `19 years` for example and I'm trying to get `2001-02-12` programmatically.

I've also tried looking for a library [here](https://pub.dev/)  but I can't find any that can help me In this case. Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure about YYYY-DD-MM and not YYYY-MM-DD?  I've never seen YYYY-DD-MM in use, and that format makes *no* sense at all.

Comment: You don't specify *how* you expect to get `2001-02-12` from "19 years".  Do you mean 19 years ago from the current date? (If so, where do you expect `02-12` to come from?)

Comment: @jamesdlin My apologies my friend I wasn't around. And I found the solution to this by simply doing calculations on nodejs server.

Answer (score 1):

for date format you can use `DateFormatter fomatter = 'yyyy-MM-dd';` , `DateTime date = DateTime(year: year);` to create the date with the correct year. Then you can format the date. `String formattedDate = formatter.format(date);`.
Choose appropriate string format value for formatter and type for formattedDate and done.
Cheers